# how bash loop only directory name excluding specific file?

Tags: bash

```
IFS=$'\n'
for CITY in $(cat /home/user/CT.txt)
do
 FILES=/mnt/dir1/dir2/$CITY/*
 count=0
folder=''
 for f in $FILES
 do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
        ((count++))
        folder=$f
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
   #cat $f
 done
```

Below is CT.txt content and directory structures :

```
cat CT.txt
Test1 Test2 Test3

cd Test1/
|_dir1
exm.xls
cd Test2
|_dir1
exm.xls
```

Output should:

i want only dir inside files should process under Test1 Test2 excluding .xls file

Comment: if the directory structure is wrong, please edit in your question

Comment: While it's the same person with the same script, it seems (to me) to be an extension of the previous question, here asking how to exclude files from the loop, versus dealing with the spaces in the previous question. That doesn't excuse the lack of progress based on the referral to: "Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?"

Answer (score 1):

Without addressing the rest of your script, to skip files that end in ".xls":

```
[[ $f =~ .xls$ ]] && continue
```

Or, if you don't like that syntax:

```
case "$f" in
  (*.xls) continue;;
esac
```

Or, if you don't like that syntax:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in /mnt/dir1/dir2/$CITY/!(*.xls)
do
  : etc
done
```

Comment: IFS=$'\n'

for CITY in $(cat /home/user/CT.txt)

do

 FILES=/mnt/dir1/dir2/$CITY/*

 count=0

folder=''

 for f in $FILES

 do

  echo "Processing $f file..."

        ((count++))

        folder=$f

i want to process only if there files folder. if there is any other file apart from that folder than exclude that.